# Bash Autocomplete Predicts Command

Tags: bash, tabs

When I press tab to autocomplete, bash predicts an available command even if there are multiple commands available.

For example, if I am in a directory with file named foobarbaz.txt and foobarbing.txt and I write:

```
$ foo
```

Pressing tab will result in

```
$ foobarbaz.txt
```

rather than the desired

```
$ foobar
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: perhaps one file has executable permissions, and the other does not?